# Only push current branch in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

In SourceTree when I push a branch it defaults to pushing every branch.  (ie Select All is checked).

Is there a way to disable this behavior and only push the current branch?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to push the current branch to the tracking remote branch you'd normally pull, go to **Tools > Options > Git** and change the **Push Branches** option to `upstream`.

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I never knew what that drop down was for.  Do you know what the other options in the list do?

Comment: Slightly more detail here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/67569/why-are-all-branches-selected-by-default-in-sourcetree-when-pushing

Comment: Is this still working for people? For me it doesn't change the fact that multiple branches are selected when a click on "Push". Extra dangerous in combination with the "Force Push" checkbox.